# How to mutate for loop in dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I want to create multiple lag variables for a column in a data frame for a range of values. I have code that successfully does what I want but is not scalable for what I need (hundreds of iterations)

I have code below that successfully does what I want but is not scalable for what I need (hundreds of iterations)

```
Lake_Lag <- Lake_Champlain_long.term_monitoring_1992_2016 %>% 
group_by(StationID,Test) %>% 
   arrange(StationID,Test,VisitDate) %>% 
   mutate(lag.Result1 = dplyr::lag(Result, n = 1, default = NA))%>% 
   mutate(lag.Result5 = dplyr::lag(Result, n = 5, default = NA))%>% 
   mutate(lag.Result10 = dplyr::lag(Result, n = 10, default = NA))%>% 
   mutate(lag.Result15 = dplyr::lag(Result, n = 15, default = NA))%>% 
   mutate(lag.Result20 = dplyr::lag(Result, n = 20, default = NA))
```

I would like to be able to use a list c(1,5,10,15,20) or a range 1:150 to create lagging variables for my data frame.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here's an approach that makes use of some 'tidy eval helpers' included in `dplyr` that come from the `rlang` package.

The basic idea is to create a new column in `mutate()` whose name is based on a string supplied by a for-loop.

```
library(dplyr)

grouped_data <- Lake_Champlain_long.term_monitoring_1992_2016 %>% 
  group_by(StationID,Test) %>% 
  arrange(StationID,Test,VisitDate)

for (lag_size in c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20)) {

  new_col_name <- paste0("lag_result_", lag_size)

  grouped_data <- grouped_data %>% 
    mutate(!!sym(new_col_name) := lag(Result, n = lag_size, default = NA))
}
```

The `sym(new_col_name) :=` is a dynamic way of writing `lag_result_1 =`, `lag_result_2 =`, etc. when using functions like `mutate()` or `summarize()` from the `dplyr` package.

Comment: This works! But I am getting two versions of the results column. For instance lag.Results1 and lag_result_1 are both columns generated and both have the correct values.

Comment: I'm guessing that the results from this approach are being added to the results from some other R code in your script. Maybe you could restart R and check to make sure that this code is replacing rather than supplementing code that adds columns of the form `lag.Results1`, `lag.Results2`, etc.

Answer (score 2):

We can use `shift` from `data.table`, which can take take multiple valuees for `n`.  According to `?shift`

> n - Non-negative integer vector denoting the offset to lead or lag the input by. To create multiple lead/lag vectors, provide multiple values to n

Convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT`), `order` by 'StationID', 'Test', 'VisitDate' in `i`, grouped by 'StationID', 'Test'), get the `lag` (default `type` of `shift` is "lag") of 'Result' with `n` as a vector of values, and assign (`:=`) the output to a vector of columns names (created with `paste0`)

```
library(data.table)
i1 <- c(1, 5, 10, 15, 20)
setDT(Lake_Champlain_long.term_monitoring_1992_2016)[order(StationID, 
    Test, VisitDate), paste0("lag.Result", i) := shift(Result, n= i),
        by = .(StationID, Test)][]
```

NOTE: Showed a much efficient solution

Comment: Im getting an error:
Error: unexpected ',' in:
"setDT(Lake_Champlain_long.term_monitoring_1992_2016)[order(StationID, Test, VisitDate), paste0("lag.Result", i) := shift(Result, n= i)],"

Comment: @BrendanEFilkins  sorry had a typo `]`, can you try now